# Can't Show data by populate in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Please Help me, i want to show Vehicles(VehiclesDB) data using populate by select CityName(namaKota) from Schema Partner(RentalDB) in mongoodb, with NodeJs.. here my code

```
export class GetVehiclesbyKotaCommandHandler {
constructor(namaKota) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        VehiclesDB.find({"namaKota":namaKota}).populate({
            path: 'mitraId',
            model: 'RentalDB',
            select: 'namaKota'
        }).lean().then((dataVehicles)=>{
            if(dataVehicles !== null){
                resolve(dataVehicles);
            } else {
                reject (new NotFoundException('Couldn\'t find any Vehicles with id' + namaKota));
            }
        }).catch((errDataVehicles)=>{
            reject(new CanNotGetVehiclesException(errDataVehicles.message));
        });
    });
}
```

}

[my Vehicles Collection Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ysk3r.png)

[My Partner(Mitra) Collection Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ql0n0.png)

But My Response is Succes and Don't Show Anything

```
{
"success": true,
"status": 200,
"message": "Successfully get kendaraan by mitraId!",
"error_code": null,
"data": []
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I am going to take a wild guess from looking at your images (better if you edit your question with your schemas) that there is a mismatch with type of `mitraId` field in your Vehicles collection and `_id` in your Partners collection.

The former is a `String` whereas the latter is an `ObjectID`. They need to be the same type in order to populate.